# Display Custom Meta Box on Wordpress Android/iOS App

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that displays a custom meta box when authoring pages and posts.  Is there any way to get this information to appear on the mobile app provided by Wordpress?  My general hunch is no - but I figured I'd ask in case i'm missing something.

Comment: You mean the WordPress App provided by Automatic (closely connected to but not strictly WordPress), correct?

Comment: @s_ha_dum correct - the automattic provided app